# получение логина телеграмм используя айди телеграмм aiogram

Tags: telegram, aiogram

У меня возникла проблема. Необходимо получить логин пользователя по его идентификатору в Телеграме (ID). Использую aiogram v3, но не понимаю, как извлечь логин из полученных данных. Заранее благодарен за поддержку!

Comment: Вообще, логин содержится тут - message.from_user.username